# Excel 2003 VBA (Extensibility): Path/File access error wnen changing name of VBComponent/Usetform at Runtime

Tags: vba, excel, extensibility

I am trying to create a Custom/Advanced Message box (because I can, or should be able to)

I looked at these resources on the wenb:

1) [MSDN - How to Programmatically Manipulate a UserForm](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185774)

2) [Programmatically Add a UserForm](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=228)

I have created a class module called 'MessageBox' in my VB project that adds a UserForm, and should add a button and then show the form...as well as added the Visual Basic Applications Extensibility reference.

But the ^&%^ code keeps giving me a Path/File Access error when I try to change the userform name...

what am I doing wrong?

```
Private oForm As Object

Function Show(Optional ByVal MessageText As String, Optional ByVal Buttons As     VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, Optional ByVal Caption As String) As VbMsgBoxResult

Dim oControl() As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim x As Integer, MaxWidth As Long

Set oForm = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)

With oForm
    .Properties("Height") = 200
    .Properties("Width") = 300
    .Properties("Caption") = Caption
        If Buttons = vbDefaultButton1 Then
            ReDim oControl(0)
            Set oControl(0) = .Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
            With oControl(0)
                .Caption = "OK"
                .Height = 18
                .Width = 44
                .Left = MaxWidth + 147
                .Top = 6
                .Name = "cmdOK"
            End With
        End If
        .Name = "cMessageBox"
    End With
    'Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Name="cMessageBox"

    ' ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents ("cMessageBox")
    With oForm.CodeModule
        x = .CountOfLines
        .InsertLines x + 1, "Sub cmdOK_Click()"
        .InsertLines x + 2, "    Unload Me"
        .InsertLines x + 3, "End Sub"
    '        .InsertLines x + 4, ""
    '        .InsertLines x + 5, "Sub CommandButton2_Click()"
    '        .InsertLines x + 6, "    Unload Me"
    '        .InsertLines x + 7, "End Sub"
    End With
    Call ShowIt

    End Function

    Private Sub ShowIt()
    cMessageBox.Show
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the form object as either `MSForms.UserForm` or `VBComponent` ?

Comment: I remember this happening to me about a year ago and I'm sure it was something like that which solved it. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: This is due to a known VBA bug: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/244238